# Why can not find the index.jsp in the web project with DD

Tags: eclipse, jsp

All, Forgive me I am the newbie in the Java web world, I am trying to write a web project for a test. But seems I didn't got the result I expected. I don't know what happen to it . Please help to review it .Here is what I done so far.

1. Create a dynamic web project named `MyFirstWeb` in the Eclipse with the option `Generate web.xml DD`.
2. Add a `index.jsp` under the directory of `WebContent`.below is the page code in it.

> ```
> <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
>     pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
>     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
> <html>
> <head>
> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
> <title>My Title</title>
> </head>
> <body>
> <% java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date(); %>
> <h1>
> Today's date is <%= d.toString() %> and this jsp page worked!
> </h1>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

And after I published it to the build-in Tomcat server run-time in the Eclipse. There is no error when the server is started.
But I got a empty page for the url `http://localhost:8080/MyFirstWeb/index.jsp`, Why? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I used your exact code in Eclipse and it is working perfectly fine. can you post what the error is.?
And check if your web.xml has this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>MyFirstWeb</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Well , I just deleted the original project , and created it again as the instructions , But It works fine . I can't find it anymore. :(  Anyway, The xml content in your answer is the default when I create the project ..thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Add to your web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: can you please explain how to do it automatically like in Netbeans??